# Can we make a certain function run when a Redux state value changes in Class Based React?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit, state-management

I'm building a project primarily using React Class Components and was wondering if there was a method that does the following:
a) Allows you to specify dependencies like the `useEffect` hook- specifically state objects saved in a Redux Toolkit slice
b) Runs certain code when one of the dependencies change

I'm aware that `componentDidUpdate()` lets you run code whenever the class' state object or props change, but I don't see a way for it to detect changes in Redux state objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`componentDidUpdate` is the way to do that. The redux state you're interested it needs to be available as props in the component, this is done via the `connect()` API. Then you can read the `prevProps` argument of `componentDidUpdate` and compare the values.

Please note that if you want to detect redux state changes *caused by your own code*, you're better off extending the code that dispatches the actions that change the state in the first place (active/imperative vs. passive/reactive).

Answer (score -1):

using [useSelector](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector) to retrieve the value from the reduc store and passing it as second argument to [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects) should allow you to achieve your need.

If you share some code sample of your issue we can drill a bit in a complete solution.

Comment: OP explicitly mentioned class components